# Autorotation distorts a rotated view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, rotation, cgaffinetransform, affinetransform, distortion

I use the view-based template to create my app, and return YES in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to support auto-rotation. Next, I add a square testView_ object (with default auto-resizing setting), and rotate it at initialization:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
    testView_.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.1);
}
```

Now, whenever I rotate the iPhone, the testView_ will be distorted. What is the reason, and how to correct it? The testView_ width and height are changed after each time I rotate the iPhone, even though it shouldn't be autoresized (and this only happens if the testView_ is rotated initially).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally my solution is to do

```
testView_.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method, then redo

```
testView_.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.1);
```

in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation. This helps solving distortion.

It is more complicated if there are also translation, scaling... involved, but the idea is there.